# How to get a single text node between Span and before br Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I want to extract text between `span` and `br` tags. In HTML below my goal is to get **Orange** text:

```
<td role="grid cell">
<span class="ui-column-title">Fruits</span>
<span id="all fruits">
"Orange"

<br>
23

</span>
</td>
```

Comment: <td role="gridecell">
<span class="ui-column-title">Fruits</span>
<span id="allfruits">
"Orange"
<br>
23
</span>
</td>

Comment: Could you show an example of your code snippet, so as to know where to start from.

Comment: @JoeSteve : Add this Html to your original post not in the comment section.However provide some code trail what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Basic solution is to split by new line character (language python):

```
all_fruits = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[id='all fruits']").text
first_fruit = all_fruits.split("\n")[0].replace('"','').strip()
```

You can use regular expression to get words:

```
import re

all_fruits = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[id='all fruits']").text
fruit_name = re.search("\w+", all_fruits, re.MULTILINE).group()
```

If you need separate numbers and fruit names, you can use regular expression, code below return two list, first with all fruit name and second numbers(language python):

```
import re

all_fruits = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[id='all fruits']").text
fruit_names = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", all_fruits, re.MULTILINE)
fruit_numbers = re.findall("[0-9]+", all_fruits, re.MULTILINE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get that with xpath, but also with plain javascript:

```
fruit = driver.execute_script("""
  return document.querySelector('[id="all fruits"]').firstChild.textContent
""")
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text **Orange** as it is a text node you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using *Java*:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("//td[@role='grid cell']//span[@id='all fruits']")))).toString());
  ```
- Using *Python*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@role='grid cell']//span[@id='all fruits']")))).strip())
  ```
- **Note** (for Python): You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```